# hidden gridview in asp.net safe?

Tags: asp.net, security, gridview, authentication, hidden

Hello guys i was wondering if its safe using hidden gridview in asp.net.
For example on the log in page use something like this for logging in?
The sql command that fills this grid located inside the asp.net sql control and is connected to this gridview.

```
For x = 0 To workerGrid.Rows.Count - 1
            If workerGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(6).Text = userBox.Text And  
              workerGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(7).Text = passwordInput.Text And   
              workerGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(10).Text = companyIdBox.Text And   
              workerGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(8).Text = "Active" Then
                y = True
                Exit For
            End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have chosen a completely wrong solution for user authentication. I recommend you change `GridView` with `SqlDataSource` to [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are not using any ORM framework in your application.

Regarding your question, even if you hide `GridView` via `Visible=false` it still saves data in `VIEWSTATE` on page. The `VIEWSTATE` is a security risk if it is not encrypted (anyone could see or modify the values from it and POST them to your page). You should secure `VIEWSTATE` to avoid fake login. Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the content is generated into the html. If so, then it is extremely unsafe, professional programmers will be able to steal everything. Also, why don't you simply use a database? Also, why don't you obfuscate your password?

Finally, you should separate your backend logic from UI. User login should never have anything to do with UI controls.